# How do I change the title of a Wordpress page within the template?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, page-title

I am setting up a wordpress theme and it has the "logo" h1 tag at the top which shows the title of the site. On the blog page specifically though I'd like to change the title in the H1 tag.

I am aware there may be some php that does something like this: if blog page show this h1 tag (code) and for every other page show this h1 tag (code).

Is this possible?

Thanks kindly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have separate template for your blog page, like `blog.php` in your theme directory.

Then you should follow below code:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'blog.php' ) ) {
    // Current Template is Blog
} else {
    // Other Pages
}
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template

**Update:**

If blog the one of your page in WordPress then follow below code:

```
if(is_page('id or slug of WP Blog Page')) {
   // This is blog page
} else {
   // This is other page
}
```

If that does not work then you should try including different header files using `get_header` function.

More Info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Suggestion: I would suggest to create new page template for your blog page and then you are good to go. You can refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) to create new page template and assign to page.

Comment: This particular theme doesn;t have a page template for the blog, in fact the title is just in the header.php file... Any ideas for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code instead of code which is now using to display the page title.

```
<?php

    if ( is_page( '{enter your blog page slug here}' ) ) {    
        echo '<h1>{enter your blog page title here}</h1>';
    } else { 
        echo '<h1>{enter your non-blog page title here}</h1>';
    }   

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query your current page template with meta.
You can get current page template this meta tag:

```
_wp_page_template
```

And full code:

```
if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true) == "your-template.php" ){
// current page is created with your template
} else{
// other page template or defult template
}
```